# No space left on device, not able to install anything

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, disk-usage, memory-usage, boot-partition

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1pljOCSln5zwNsQO5gcv5Kx1qNM7KH-Uh

Please refer to the above link. My 19GB `/` partition is 100% full. I understand that root `/` partition `/dev/sda8` is filled, but I guess I was expecting partition `/dev/sda6` to get filled because that's where it shows 80GB space. I'm unable to install anything now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: search in your home for big files like VM's or videos and mv then to another harddrive.

Comment: But isn't that just a temporary fix?

Comment: @MalikaArora That comment is indeed a temporary fix as you commented and it won't solve the problem.

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu, you did not select to use "Partition 6" as your `/home`, but you can do it manually afterwards. You need to mount "Partition 6" manually first, then move your `/home` to "Partition 6" and then set up mount on startup using `fstab`. See linked answer

Comment: where is your /dev/sda6 mounted ? I don't see it anywhere in the "df" output you provided. So how do you expect the system to use it if it's not mounted anywhere?

Comment: If your system is 17.04 or later reinstalling would solve all your problems because new installations of 17.04 and later use a swap file instead of a swap partition. Deleting the unecessary swap partition would put sda6 next to sda8 and you could merge sda6, swap and sda8 into a single 124GB partition for the new Ubuntu installation.

Comment: I realized that my root directory was wrong. I took the backup of my files, cleared the partitions and reinstalled Ubuntu. It works fine now.